# how to convert date '2020-08-21', into this format 2020-08-21T00:00:00-07:00?

Tags: python, date, datetime

I need to convert command line argument date from '2020-08-20' format to '2020-08-21T00:00:00-07:00' format?

I tried

```
from datetime import datetime

datetime.strptime(start_date, "%Y-%m-%d").date()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```py
from datetime import datetime
datetime.strptime(start_date, '%Y-%m-%d').isoformat()
```

Python version: 3.8